# Drupal: Can Book layout menu be added and expanded in the primary menu?

Tags: drupal

I'd like to take a book menu and just add it right to the primary links. Any way to do that? It can appear alreayd in the Navigation links but I'd like it to expand to deeper child levels.

Also, I'm using a theme (Newswire) that creates a suckerfish menu from the primary links, so if I can automatically add my book pages to the primary links that would be ideal...

[Sample Book Layout](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_X_AP8dD0ATQ/S05A3vKdvbI/AAAAAAAACXw/JrZi12nW290/book%20pages.JPG)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want Menu Block(http://drupal.org/project/menu_block)

Menu Block will allow you to create blocks from different menus with several customizable features (always expanded, start at parent/child/tertiary, sort by active, etc).

I usually have my entire site navigation in primary links and then use menu block to surface what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and found that the [Category module](http://drupal.org/project/category) did the job for me.  Instead of organising pages into books, you organise them into containers and categories.  The module is able to automatically populate menus from the container and category structure.  It's a bit more complex than the Book module, but far more flexible.